# How do I set up custom ActiveRecord association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have three Model that I need to connect.

These models are:

```
Container

Item

ItemProperty
```

I can not figure out how to find all the items belonging to the container. Each Item has many ItemProperties associated with it. Out of these Item properties there is at least one that has the one that has the following data.

```
#   id: 2164
#   property_key: container_id
#   property_value_integer: 1
#   world_item_id: 438
#   property_value_type: integer
#   is_active: 1
```

How would I find which Items belong to container based on the ItemProperty which contains

```
property_key: container_id
property_value_integer: 1 (this is the id of the container)
```

Please help, thank you!

Current Associations:

```
class ItemProperty < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :item, :class_name => 'Item', :foreign_key => 'item_id'
end

class Item < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :item_properties
end
```

Comment: I'm not understanding your question. Could you clearly illustrate how the foreign keys are set up for each model? Also, does every item property have a property_value_integer, or only some?

Comment: It looks like your ItemProperty doesn't have an `item_id` attributes. But there is a `world_item_id` attributes. I am confused...

Comment: What code did you try and what was the error that it showed?

Answer (score 1):

Try this. The key take away here is the ***has_many*** xxx, **:through=>** yyy

```
class Container < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :item #or has_many :items depending on your needs
 has_many :item_properties, :through => :items
end 

class Item < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :item_properties
end  

class ItemProperty < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :item, :class_name => 'Item', :foreign_key => 'item_id'
end
```

You can then query for the container(s) of a selected item property. Hope it helps.